# How to change google docs file owner without sending an email notice to the new owner

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am using Drive API with Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp to change a file owner. It works great and it sends an email notice for every single file to the new owner. How can I suppress this email notice?

Here is my partial code snippet

```
var base = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('docs', base);
fetchArgs.method = 'POST';

var rawXml = "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gAcl='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007'>"
+"<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' "
+"term='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessRule'/>"
+"<gAcl:role value='owner'/>"
+"<gAcl:scope type='user' value='"+newOwnerEmail+"'/>"
+"</entry>";

fetchArgs.payload = rawXml;
fetchArgs.contentType = 'application/atom+xml';
var url = base + encodeURIComponent(oldOwnerEmail) + '/private/full/'+fileOrFolderId+'/acl?v=3&alt=json';
var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getContentText();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add `sendNotificationEmails=false` to your request to modify the permissions of the file

Comment: Thank you it is now working, e.g. no longer sending the unwanted emails. 

P.S. I realized I am using docs.google.com, so I had to use send-notification-emails=false